# Power Query M - We cannot convert the value null to type Logical

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

In Power BI I have an M Query that tests for the value in a column equaling or not equaling to `null`.

When I add the statement for `[Sale.Revenue] <> null` I get an error however it works fine for the `[UserRole.Name] = null` it works fine. Tested just by removing the statement and adding it back.

`We cannot convert the value null to type Logical.`

This seems like it should work but just can't figure it out.

```
add_user_role_group = Table.AddColumn(
    join_expand_sale, 
    "UserRole.Group1", 
    each (
      if [UserRole.Name] = null and
         [Sale.Revenue] <> null then
        "Group1"
      else if Text.Contains([UserRole.Name], "Manager") then
        "Group2"
      else
        "Undefined"
    )
  )
```

I am sure it is something glaringly obvious :/ Thanks for your thoughts on this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One of your rows has a null value for both UserRole.Name and Sale.Revenue. You need to check for that explicitly, and then add it to the "Undefined" group.

What happened is that the first condition fails because Sale.Revenue is null. The second condition calls Text.Contains, which returns null when [UserRole.Name] is null (Text.Contains returns a nullable logical value). null is not true or false, so you get the error.

Comment: Thanks mate. I had a think about your answer and I first tested for UserRole.Name = null, started a new if statement inside of that and then dealt with the null revenue after the last else statement. Thank you for your insight.

Answer (score 3):

After a such journey, finaly I found **Text.Length !!**

You can solve your problem like this:

```
if Text.Length([UserRole.Name]) = 0 and
         Text.Length([Sale.Revenue]) > 0 then
```

I hope I have helped you.
Reference: [Power Query M - Text.Length](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/text-length)

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is in the Text.Contains formula. You create an if statement that expects an expression that returns either true or false.

When the Text.Contains formula contains a null value, it returns 'null' as answer, and not true or false. You can adjust your code:

```
Text.Contains([UserRole.Name], "Manager")
```

To

```
Text.Contains([UserRole.Name]??"", "Manager")
```

The ?? is the COALESCE operator. In case it finds a null value, it now treats it as "". Instead of returning null it now returns true or false.

More on text functions in this article: https://gorilla.bi/power-query/text-functions/

Enjoy Power Query,

Rick